# Interrogative section headings are fine in a tech business blog?

Tags: structure, blog, titles, headlines

I have a feeling that I overuse questioned headings in my writings about tech and business issues. I don't want to give examples of texts but, believe me, I use (or want to use) it very frequently both in section bodies and section headings, and sometimes I even limit myself on doing this.

At the same time, for example, on LI and Medium which subject area mostly fits my articles, they have multiple articles that follow this pattern: [example 1](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/end-digital-marketing-expert-era-geoffrey-colon/), [example 2](https://medium.com/darius-foroux/struggle-with-self-discipline-try-forming-these-habits-168bdc3ae510).

Having searched Writing SE I found a couple of questions of the same matter, but my question is different [from this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/14516/can-section-headings-in-a-paper-be-questions) is that asker from the above question was writing academic paper, and [from this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/36105/should-structuring-an-academic-text-with-the-help-of-questions-be-avoided) for the same reason. The professor from the latter [points out](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/36106/43055) is that

> That is a form of "entertainment" and entertainment is NOT the goal of a paper

and this is quite contrary to what I want in my blog. I am not writing academic research, I don't use MLA style nor any other, and I want that my articles would not be pure theory so **I deliberately want them contain entertainment element**, want them explain complex problems and issues pegged to reader experience and his everyday needs in a popular form. Is this a fair point?

Also I believe in power of headings, many writing guides and hints [encircle](http://www.thepenmagazine.net/20-steps-to-write-a-good-article/) importance of proper structuring of the essays and mention such concepts as [layout and outline](https://explorable.com/tips-on-article-writing), Writers SE answers also confirms that skimming [definitely exists](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/36733/43055) and non-eye-catching headers will simply be skimmed. I consider correct and precise questions is a good way to catch and focus attention of a reader on some section.

The main assumption I use in my reasoning behind interrogative style of heading and bodies is that **potential reader is not familiar with article topic at all or not quite familiar at least with the angle I use to cover that topic**.

Is it a fair point or by (over)using questions I bring some preachy tune into my blog thus making it arrogant for reader?

P.S. Where is that thin line between use and overuse of questions? How to catch it?

Comment: Not an answer, but your title "question" *isn't*.  "Are Interrogative section headings fine in a tech business blog?" is a question, "Interrogative section headings are fine in a tech business blog." is a statement.  Question marks are for Direct Questions.

Answer (score 1):

Overuse of any technique is undesirable, whether it's alliteration, personification, exaggeration or whatever. Overuse of short sentences or long sentences or compound ones or complex ones is unwanted.

Questions can be very useful. You can pose the question the readers themselves have. You can plant ideas and create ownership of those ideas. However, if the reader starts to notice them that isn't good.

There isn't a rule which says you can only use one or two or six. That is the tough bit about writing. You have to work out what sounds good and what sounds bad.

Comment: you raised exactly the same concern that I put in the end: *Where is that thin line between use and overuse of questions?* :)